# mod_rewrite help

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having mod_rewrite problems.  A full explanation, plus logs is below:

```
############################################################
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /managedDir
RewriteRule login/client/$ /managedDir/index.php?user= [L]
RewriteRule login/(.*)/admin-lostpassword/$ /managedDir/admin/content/admin-lostpassword.php [L]
RewriteRule login/(.*)/$ /managedDir/index.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule user.(.*)/page/(.*)/$ /managedDir/index.php?user=$1&page=$2
############################################################
```

I'm currently having a lot of trouble logging into
http://localhost/managedDir/login/client/ but I can login to:
http://localhost/managedDir/login/admin/

Here are the error.log:

```
[Sat May 28 16:57:13 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MDFramework\\index.php on line 133, referer: /managedDir/login/client/
[Sat May 28 16:57:13 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: /managedDir/login/client/
[Sat May 28 16:57:13 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP 1. {main}() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MDFramework\\index.php:0, referer: /managedDir/login/client/
[Sat May 28 16:57:14 2011] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
```

Here is the access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - admin [28/May/2011:16:57:13 -0500] "POST /managedDir/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26661 "/managedDir/login/client/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
127.0.0.1 - admin [28/May/2011:16:57:14 -0500] "GET /managedDir/user.client/page/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "/managedDir/login/client/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
```

When I login to /login/admin/ it correctly loads the page and logs in. but when I login to /login/client/ it gives me a blank page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably:

```
[Sat May 28 16:57:14 2011] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
```

Don't add the DEFLATE header because your webserver doesn't understand it?

Possibly relevant: http://www.divideandconquer.se/2008/02/27/an-unknown-filter-was-not-added-deflate/